# process SVG to continuous, "no move"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector, inkscape, python

I am working with continuous script fonts and I need to generate a single path that do not include M commands. This would be equivalent to writing without lifting the pen from the paper.

My input is an inkscape produced svg that today contains 84 paths, each of them have multiple svg M commands.

[image: biology pictue]

How do I process this SVG so that it contains a single, continuous path without any "moves". (I am aware I will loose the tittle/dot on the letter i!)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem or how you got there, but why start with multiple paths when you can simply [use the Bézier Tool](https://imgur.com/885UgcF) to make one continuous path?

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to build (code/script) something that could process those files automatically. Perhaps the right way to phrase the question is that if there is a way to automate the making of a continuous Bézier from one that is not continuous.

Comment: If you mean to automate/process something that looks good, but starting out from something that looks as bad as your example, then probably not - at least not that I am aware of.  Also I think your question may be getting slightly off-topic now, since it seems to now be a coding question rather than a graphic design one.

Comment: Because computers are less intuitive than people, it's usually only practical to program them to do something like this when the way they should do it is completely obvious. Your image has lots of end points and points where three lines come out. These are discontinuities, places where the computer must make a decision as to what comes next and eventually retrace its steps. It would probably be easiest to redraw the characters, but if you want a program to do it for you, first you must clarify exactly what rules that program must follow when it reaches a discontinuity.

Comment: Aren't there any ready-made continuous script fonts that you could use?

Comment: A script continuous script font would probably solve my problem (can you point me to any?), but all the ones I've have found had were not really "one stroke", meaning they had contours, fills and one svg path per letter (that could be merged, but that is the reason for my question).